# How to mock a method call inside a method for a JUnit test?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class that I am trying to write unit tests for (I didn't create the class) and I'm not sure how to just test one method.

The class (ShapeUtility in this example) class looks something like this:

```
public ShapeUtility(ShapeConfig config) {
    this.config = config;
}

public CircleDetails getDetails() {
    CircleDetails cDetails = new CircleDetails();
    //stuff
    cDetails = getSize();
    //stuff
    return cDetails;
}

public CircleDetails getSize() {
    CircleDetails cDetails = new CircleDetails();
    //stuff
    cDetails.setSize(size);
    //stuff
    return cDetails;
}
```

I looked around on the web and was using this as an example to mock it: https://www.stevenschwenke.de/spyingWithMockito

What I want to do for the JUnit is something like this (so the method `getSize` doesn't actually get called within the `getDetails` method):

```
ShapeConfig config = new ShapeConfig();
ShapeUtility utility = new ShapeUtility(config);

CircleDetails cDetails = spy(new CircleDetails());
when(cDetails.getSize().thenReturn(5));

utility.getDetails();
```

However, the `cDetails` doesn't get passed in to the ShapeUtility methods so this doesn't work. Is there another way to do this? Or should I just look into rewriting the code so that a CircleDetails object gets passed in to the ShapeUtility methods?

Comment: I've read your question at least three times and still don't know what the exact problem is. Maybe you should go over it again.

Comment: @DoeJohnson The problem is that I'm trying to do something like when(cDetails.getSize) but in the actual code it is cDetails = getSize(), which is a method within the ShapeUtility class. What I want to do is when the getSize method is called within the ShapeUtility method getDetails I want to set cDetails equal to some mocked value (meaning that getSize isn't actually called)

Comment: @SuperCow please note that your `getSize()` method not returns number. I believe that it's just typo, right?

Comment: @gokareless good catch, and yes just a typo

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want to test one method while, mocking other one within the same class, that is why you trying to use partial mocks. Here is what I suggest for your case:

```
ShapeConfig config = mock(new ShapeConfig());
CircleDetails cDetails = mock(new CircleDetails());
ShapeUtility utility = new ShapeUtility(config);
// here is our spy
ShapeUtility spyUtility = spy(utility);

// here I assume that you have two getSize() methods, first in CircleDetails which returns number 
// and second in ShapeUtility, which returns CircleDetails 
when(cDetails.getSize().thenReturn(5));
when(spyUtility.getSize().thenReturn(cDetails));

// and then your assertion code
// assertThat(spyUtility.getDetails()...
```

Hope it will help.